# Basic Generic object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework. All my database objects (entities) have audit fields such as 'LastUpdateUserId, LastUpdateDate...'

I want to have a generic class that accepts any of these entity objects, and populates the fields for me.

So far, I have:

```
public void PopulateAudit<T>(T entity)
{

}
```

But I can't seem to work out how to reference my entities, update the properties, and then return them.

How can I do this in a generic fashion, so that I can call a method on my objects to update the fields?

So that I can do something like this:

```
a = Context.accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == dto.Id);
PopulateAudit(a);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please give us an example of your `main object` and an `entity object`

Comment: I updated the question. All my objects are Entity Framework entity objects.

Comment: Instead of the generic approach you could derive all your entity objects from a single "Audit" base class that contains your audit properties and fill these properties by overriding the SaveChanges-method of your context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably define a base interface with your common properties and then write this as an extension method:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    string LastUpdateUserID { get; set; }
    DateTime LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
}

public static class EntityExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension Method for IEntity
    /// </summary>
    public static void PopulateAudit<T>(this T entity)
        where T: IEntity
    {
        entity.LastUpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
        entity.LastUpdateUserID = "john.doe"; //or pull this from a service somewhere
    }
}
```

You could then simply call it on your entity:

```
a = Context.accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == dto.Id);
a.PopulateAudit();
```

Alternatively, you could just define it as a non-extension method if you want to have better IoC options:

```
public class SomeServiceClass
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public SomeServiceClass(IUserService userService)
    {
        this._userService = userService;
    }

    public void PopulateAudit<T>(this T entity)
        where T: IEntity
    {
        entity.LastUpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
        entity.LastUpdateUserID = this._userService.GetCurrentUser();
    }
}

a = Context.accounts.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == dto.Id);
someServiceInstance.PopulateAudit(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

If all of your objects inheit from a common base class you dont have to use templates

```
void Main()
{
    var dt = new MyData();
    FillTracking(dt);
}

public void FillTracking(TrackableObject obj)
{
    obj.LastUpate = DateTime.Now;
}

public class TrackableObject
{
    public DateTime LastUpate { get; set; }
}

public class MyData : TrackableObject
{

}
```

Otherwise you can use reflection..

```
void Main()
{
    var dt = new MyData();
    FillTracking(dt);
}

public void FillTracking(object data)
{   
    data.GetType().GetProperty("LastUpdate").SetValue(data, DateTime.Now);
}

public class MyData
{
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

Keep in mind, the reflection code is not complete and you will need to check for the existence of the property before you try to set it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`AutoMapper`](http://automapper.org/) to copy entity objects to POCO objects. [Here is a good walk-through](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61629/AutoMapper) and [here](http://www.geospecialling.com/index.php/2010/06/effortlessly-map-domain-and-dto-entities/) of how to use it.